# How to measure the statistical "distance" between two frequency distributions?

Tags: distributions, distance, frequency, divergence

I am undertaking a data analysis project which involves investigating website usage times over the course of the year. What I would like to do is compare how "consistent" the usage patterns are, say, how close they are to a pattern which involves using it for 1 hour once per week, or one which involves using it for 10 minutes a time, 6 times per week. I am aware of several things which can be calculated:

- **Shannon entropy:** measures how much the "certainty" in the outcome differs, i.e. how much a probability distribution differs from one that is uniform;
- **Kullback-Liebler divergence:** measures how much one probability distribution differs from another
- **Jensen-Shannon divergence:** similar to the KL-divergence, but more useful as it returns finite values
- **Smirnov-Kolmogorov test**: a test to determine whether two cumulative distribution functions for continuous random variables come from the same sample.
- **Chi-squared test:** a goodness-of-fit test to decide how well a frequency distribution differs from an expected frequency distribution.

What I would like to do is compare how much the actual usage durations (blue) differ from ideal usage times (orange) in distribution. These distributions are discrete, and the versions below are normalised to become probability distributions. The horizontal axis represents the amount of time (in minutes) a user has spent on the website; this has been recorded for each day of the year; if the user has not gone on the website at all then this counts as a zero duration but these have been removed from the frequency distribution. On the right is the cumulative distribution function.

[image: Distribution of website usage data versus ideal usage data]

My only problem is, even though I can get the JS-divergence to return a finite value, when I look at different users and compare their usage distributions to the ideal one, I get values that are mostly identical (which is therefore not a good indicator of how much they differ). Also, quite a bit of information is lost when normalising to probability distributions rather than frequency distributions (say a student uses the platform 50 times, then the blue distribution should be vertically scaled so that the total of the lengths of the bars equals 50, and the orange bar should have a height of 50 rather than 1). Part of what we mean by "consistency" is whether how often a user goes on the website affects how much they get out of it; if the number of times they visit the website is lost then comparing probability distributions is a bit dubious; even if the probability distribution of a user's duration is close to the "ideal" usage, that user may only have used the platform for 1 week during the year, which arguably is not very consistent.

Are there any well-established techniques for comparing two *frequency* distributions and calculating some sort of metric which characterises how similar (or dissimilar) they are?

Comment: You might want to start by asking yourself what your loss function is (that is, in what way is usage pattern differing from the ideal bad, and how does the amount of badness depend on what sort of divergence there is), and designing your metric around that.

Answer (score 18):

You may be interested in the [Earth mover's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover's_distance), also known as the [Wasserstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric). It is implemented in R (look at the `emdist` package) and in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5101004/452096). We also have [a number of threads on it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=earth+mover).

The EMD works for both continuous and discrete distributions. The `emdist` package for R works on discrete distributions.

The advantage over something like a $\chi^2$ statistic is that the EMD yields *interpretable* results. Picture your distribution as mounds of earth, then the EMD tells you how much earth you would need to transport how far to turn one distribution into the other.

Put another way: two distributions (1,0,0) and (0,1,0) should be "more similar" than (1,0,0) and (0,0,1). The EMD will recognize this and assign a smaller distance to the first pair than to the second. The $\chi^2$ statistic will assign the same distance to both pairs, because it has no notion of an ordering in the distribution entries.

Comment: Why that particular distance? It seems to be designed for any continuous distribution. OP has a frequency distribution, so why not a more "discrete" distance such as Chi-square?

Comment: @user2974951: fair enough. See my edit.

Comment: if distributions are 1D, as suggested in the question, then running and EMD solver is overkill. What needs to be done in that case is just compute a $L_p$ metric between the empirical quantile functions of both densities (essentially the inverses of the CDFs plotted in the quesion). p.31 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00567 or if you need a more detailed account chapter 2 of https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~filippo/OTAM-cvgmt.pdf

Comment: @MarcoCuturi: an $L^p$ distance is certainly another possibility. However, it will again assign the same distance between (1,0,0) and (0,1,0) as between (1,0,0) and (0,0,1), which is a bit unintuitive. Whether the added intuitive niceness of the EMD is worth the additional complexity is something the OP can consider.

Answer (score 3):

If you randomly sample an individual from each of the two distributions, you can calculate a difference between them. If you repeat this (with replacement) a number of times, you can generate a distribution of differences that contains all the information you are after. You can plot this distribution and characterize it with any summary statistics you desire - means, medians, etc.

Comment: Is there a name for such a procedure?

Comment: I wonder how one could account for the baseline fact that the distribution of differences for an arbitrary distribution and itself will be different for different arbitrary distributions; think U(0,1) vs. itself compared to N(0,1) vs. itself. Hence, the distribution of differences you would get comparing two different distributions would be hard to evaluate in absence of a unique baseline. The problem disappears if the observations are paired, then the baseline would be a unit mass at zero.

Comment: @user2974951 I'm sure there is, as it's pretty simple and clearly related to bootstrapping. But I don't know what to call it precisely.

Comment: @RichardHardy Good point, that is an important concern. I think how large of a problem it is would depend on how one plans to interpret and use the distribution of differences. If interpretation is restricted to the case at hand, this may be acceptable, though caution would be warranted when drawing conclusions. It's more of a problem if one is trying to compare distributions of differences across domains where different underlying data distributions might arise.

Comment: Not sure if we are agreeing or disagreeing here, but let me reiterate that without a baseline, interpreting the results might be very difficult. I do not immediately see how this should depend on whether we are interested in a single case or comparing across domains. Taking an example, when we do not have a ruler, it is very difficult to measure how tall a person is, regardless of the circumstances and context.

Comment: @RichardHardy Perhaps I misunderstand you. I think it's difficult to create single metrics that can provide an answer that is general and easy to interpret. The distribution of differences I suggest serves as a starting point; a proper interpretation will need to take into account the specifics of the problem. To use your example, we have a ruler and two different groups of people and want to know how different the groups are. Choosing pairs of people at random and looking at the distribution of height differences of the pairs seems like a reasonable way to begin.

Comment: @RichardHardy The point about domains was that it would not make a lot of sense to compare this distribution of height differences with, say, a distribution of differences in electricity consumption of groups of cities.

Comment: @mkt, thanks for your clarification. Without intending to argue just for the sake it, I still think that without a unique baseline we do not quite have a ruler. But I will leave it at that. There is something nice about your idea anyway.

Comment: @RichardHardy I appreciate the exchange here, and you might well be right. I'll have to think about this further.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you a bit, but this sounds like the core component of the [energy distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_distance), a special case of the "maximum mean discrepancy" and also related to the Wasserstein/earth mover's distance from the other answer.

Comment: @Dougal Thanks, this is interesting. I was not aware of the energy distance or the earth mover's distance before this.

Answer (score 0):

One of the metric is Hellinger distance between two distributions which are characterised by means and standard deviations. The application can be found in the following article.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1568494615005104

Comment: Thanks for that. I have seen that there is a whole family of divergences (f-divergences) which do what I want, but a quick flick through the literature doesn't seem to indicate which is best when... do you know of any good literature on this?