# Calculating how close a model distribution is to the data distribution

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions

A lot of machine learning models aim to approximate probability distributions. Let’s say P is the distribution of the data and Q is the distribution learned by our model. How do you measure how close Q is to P?

Please include sources/references if possible.

This question is from Chip Huyens [ML interviews book](https://huyenchip.com/ml-interviews-book/contents/7.3-objective-functions,-metrics,-and-evaluation.html)

Comment: It may depend on whether you are dealing with univariate or multivariate distributions and whether the random variables are continuous or discrete.  Wikipedia has a list of [statistical distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_distance)

Comment: and there are answers on this site such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/425040/how-to-measure-the-statistical-distance-between-two-frequency-distributions and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4044/measuring-the-distance-between-two-multivariate-distributions and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78405/measuring-distance-between-two-empirical-distributions

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76350/goodness-of-fit-for-continuous-variables might help as well.